# Error while printing a string with special characters in PHP, with json_encode

Tags: php, special-characters, json

I need to print the following string but got another output in php.

```
   $test = "?s'd – b]zel/";
   echo $test;
```

and the output is:: ?s'd â€“ b]zel/ 
I need the same string on output. The character '-' is special character in Nepali font. But, it's showing â€“ instead of –. So, what will be the solution??

EDIT
when i used json_encode($test), I got output "?s'd \u2013 b]zel/". But I dont need unicode, I need "?s'd – b]zel/" as output. What should I do??

Comment: Check your html page charset and php file charset. They must be equal and supported by used font.

Comment: Try this addslashes($test); http://fr2.php.net/addslashes

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you specify the charset of your page:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

You need to make sure that every part of your application is UTF-8. Database connection, table data, page charset, etc. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/491494)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're running PHP on the console - if that's the case, you should change the console settings.

If you're running on the web - you should either change the page encoding or escape the character you're displaying. This can be done by adding the following to your HTML:

Comment: You've got 2/3 wrong. Why would you assume he's running PHP on the console? Very few people do that, very **very** few beginners do that. Also, escaping your characters wouldn't help you in a charset problem.

Comment: So did I. HTML escaping would solve nothing in this case, because the document itself might not be UTF8. If it *is*, and you're confident that the character in the document is the character you want displayed, then HTML escaping could work. But the base assumption is not necessarily correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because you use UTF8 encoded characters (so your `–` is NOT "normal" dash `-` but at the same time your HTML document is not using UTF8 encoding, falling back to (usually) Latin1. Either "clean" your `$test` string, or fix HTML to correctly declare used encoding:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
```

Comment: Just to let you know (in case you didn't already), `<meta charset="utf-8">` acts exactly the same way as `<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">` in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your document and HTML encoding are the same (recommended, UTF8).

Your PHP charset is set by the **text editor** you are using.

Your HTML charset can be determined by sending a header (which is the recommended way!)

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```